# Spring internalisation

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

English properties file can be read bt when i click on french link it couldnt read.Can u tell me the stepwise process to do this.I hav images which need to be in french when i click in french..

Comment: If you can't be bothered to ask a clear question I can't be bothered to answer. Proper grammar would help, too. Stackoverflow is not a "give-me-teh-codez" site.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses the [ResourceBundle](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) class to support internationalization.  `ResourceBundle` can load it's content from property files on the classpath.  To provide property files for all the languages/countries you want, you need multiple property files, each named in this format baseName_languageCode_countryCode.properties

All properties files must have the same *baseName*.  *languageCode* is to specify a language, and is 2 lower-case characters.  *countryCode* is to specify the country, and is 2 upper-case characters. You can make sure you're using the correct codes by checking out values used in the [Locale](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) class.  To supply a properties file for French (the language) and France (the country) it would be *baseName*_fr_FR.properties.

Spring uses the [MessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html) interface to provide access to messages. [ResourceBundleMessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html) and subclasses provides an internationalizable `MessageSource`.

When configuring your `ResourceBundleMessageSource` in Spring, you'll need to supply the baseName, and place the property files somewhere on the classpath. Spring figures out the users current locale from their browser and uses it to load the correct properties file.